# find -exec cat {} code injection

Tags: linux, find, cat

I was reading the man of find on the -exec *command* {} switch section, it states that the {} should be quoted to protect from interpretation by shells.

I'm trying to reproduce such a behaviour locally without any success and wondering in what context does that interpretation apply.

Here is what i am doing trying to get that interpretation to work:

```
echo "Hi" > f1
touch -- \$\(ls\ \-la\) -n
find ./ -type f -exec cat {} +
```

Just basically trying to get either a switch or a command to be interpreted as it's parsing the malicious file names, but it doesn't get interpreted as suggested in the man.

What am i missing ?

Alternatively is there a way to exploit such a line code with cat as a command and not any other ?

Comment: I expect it to depend on the shell.

Answer (score 0):

In many shells, the braces start a brace expansion. But sh-compatible shells, Zsh and (t)csh still leave the plain `{}` alone. However, at least the fish shell doesn't, it removes an unquoted `{}`, and e.g. `echo {}` would then output just an empty line. That would break the `find` command using `{}`, so you need to quote the braces.

It's not about the filename being processed for shell expansions after `find` fills it it. At that point, there's no shell involved, unless you explicitly invoke one.

Comment: I see so if I understand well, in bash there would be no way to inject malicious code through that specific command  " find ./ -type f -exec cat {} + " because the cat won't evaluate anything that's being fed by the find result but rather with something like "find ./ -type f -exec sh -c " cmd {}" \;

Comment: @FeatherAndInk, yes. And to prevent that being an issue, you'd run `find ./ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$1"' sh {} \;` instead. Also note that `find` isn't required to expand `{}` in the middle of an argument, so the broken version might not even work.

Comment: In the case of `fish`, that changed in 3.0.0. See my answer in the [GNU find and masking the {} for some shells - which?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/247786) duplicate.